# Make a button to open the "send files" window of DropzoneJS

Tags: dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm currently making a dropzone to upload photos and it working well on Desktop But in mobile, when i click to the zone, sometimes the "Upload from files" window doesn't opening So due to this problem, i'm currently looking to add a button under the dropzone called "Choose photos to upload". This button is suposed open the "Upload from files" Window but i haven't found any help for that in the documentation.

Also on Desktop, when a file is uploaded, the message is disappearing, but i want to make them always visible. There is a specific option or i'm forced to use CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a few months old but saw nobody had answered it yet. It is entirely possible to do both parts of your question.

**Video walkthrough of how to add the upload button and force the message to always be visible**: https://youtu.be/_CCojUWu2uQ

**Working CodePen**: https://codepen.io/vpolston/pen/BaxYxNg

**HTML**
=> Create a parent wrapper div around your dropzone and HTML button element with a given ID.

```
<div id="dropZone">
  <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-great-dropzone"></form>
  <button>Add Files...</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript =>** Use the clickable property of your Dropzone and give it the value of your wrapper div.

```
Dropzone.options.myGreatDropzone = { 
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  paramName: "file", 
  maxFilesize: 2, 
  clickable: "#dropZone" // the ID of our parent wrapper div
};
```

And then tackling your second question on making sure the 'Drop files here to upload' message is always visible we must modify the CSS. Default functionality of Dropzone sets the display property of this selector to none..

**CSS =>** My solution was to set it to display: block with !important.

```
.dropzone.dz-started .dz-message {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Hopefully that helps. If so please mark answered :)